# how to manually insert data in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-data

I am using core data first time. so I know how to insert data manually in core data.
First of all I have .csv file but I don't know how to insert data into core data from this .csv file

```
My entity name is: "HatList"
attribute1: "Category id"
attribute2: "Hat id"
attribute3: "Hat name"
```

I have read various  links like [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629736/how-to-add-data-manually-in-core-data-entity) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738676/iphone-core-data-inserting-new-objects)

and other than these I have searched a lot but I didn't get proper idea.

so, can anyone give me proper code or information about my question?

Comment: try this 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102460/how-to-perform-a-insert-update-with-core-data

Answer (score 0):

Theres not a magical way to put the .csv into coredata, you have to parse it using NSScaner for example, like here: http://macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data and then insert it as a managed object.

Alternatively you can try googling for a library that does this for you, im sure there has to be one.